# Is this proof that $f$ is Riemann integrable correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded, non constant function. We know that f is integrable in $[c,b]$ $\forall c \in [a,b]$. Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable in $[a,b]$.

I have tried to prove it by saying that, as $f$ is integrable in $[c,b]$ $\forall c\in [a,b]$, I can take $c = a+ \varepsilon$, which implies that $f$ in integrable in $[a+\varepsilon,b]$; and since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrarily small, it's equivalent to saying that $f$ is integrable in $(a,b]$. Then, since adding $a$ to that set would give another point where $f$ is either continuous (which would mean that it's still integrable) or discontinuous (which would cause a finite number of discontinuities, 1, therefore making $f$ integrable), $f$ must be integrable in [a,b].

Is the reasoning correct?

Comment: Do you even (directly) define R.I with respect no non-closed intervals? More importantly, you did not use that $f$ is bounded though it is crucial!

Comment: If you are using the theorem "A bounded $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable iff the discontinuities of $f$ have measure zero", then your solution is okay. But you should mention the theorem to be clear.

Comment: Your solution is not correct.  Your solution would “prove” that $f(x) = 1/x$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ (which it is not).  As Hagen von Eitzen mentioned, you really need the fact that $f$ is bounded.  I assume you have learned about upper and lower sums?  I would suggest showing that for any $\varepsilon$ you can find a partition $\mathcal{P}$ so that $U(f,\mathcal{P}) - L(f, \mathcal{P}) < \varepsilon$.

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize that being bounded was such a crucial fact. Thanks